# Liquid 3D Object

Tags: unity

Okey now there is something I have been Struggling with for the past 2 Days, I think I am stupid or something. I need to make a Liquid 3D Object, It is really complicated what I need to make. so I will just explain it on something similar.
Imagine I need to create a Tap of water that produce blue Cubes to a swimming pool.

Object water Cube :
- They cannot Rotate.
- Their position on vector3 must be int. meaning if water cube happens to land on (1,0,1.2) it will be transformed to position (1,0,1)
- They have a Collision Detection Event

```
if(water cube collides with another water cube top surface of the cube){

Position of the top cube will be transformed to any empty cube around the first water cube scaling (X and Z) positions with circular radius of (15,15)
// Now I already achieved this through a double for loop to scan for empty, and if there is not the water cuble will stay in same position.
// Point is what if there is a wall object found while scanning for empty, it will transform position of the water to someplace behind the wall and I do not need that. and If I stopped the water from going to that direction maybe that is not a wall and just a block there.
}
```

**So what will be the code to fix this issue and preventing such a bug to happen**.
Pictures for illustration : 
[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you already have a plan for solving your problem, and you just need to implement it.  If I'm reading that correctly, you haven't really asked a question.  In any case, it might help to elaborate about what exactly you are missing from your solution (what is your question), and what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: My algorithm for allocating empty Block around the water cube have a bug which can take it behind the walls. and if I let the loop to stop in the direction where the block is found, maybe it is actually not a wall but Just a Pillar, I still need the water to go around the Pillar.

I need a Code or an Algorithm that is more efficient than mine and bug free.

Comment: But you haven't posted any code.  Are you asking for code to be written fresh, according to your description?

Comment: Update : my algorithm lags so hard upon collision. I think I am doing it wrong, I even looked for any assets on the asset market to import yet All Liquid related stuff are either 2D or 3D particals system which wont work as These water cubes will still have functions later on.

So yea, I think I am looking for a new fresh code.